# TypeErro: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: reactjs

Am new to reactjs and am implementing a to do app using controlled component but am getting an error. Type Error: this.state is null!

Comment: kindly please share the code.

Comment: Show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized your state in a constructor? You can do this by creating a constructor function in your class, e.g.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {todoList: []};
  }
```

Then you can add your todo's by doing this:

```
let todoListChange = this.state.todoList;
todoListChange.push("Clean my toilet");
this.setState({todoList: todoListChange});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your state. Default state is `null`.

```
class App from React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { todos: [] }
   }

   render () {
     // your implementation 
   }

}
```